# How to apply css label for only a specified class

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the first label bold (row 1) and then the second one (row 2) not use the div.row label declaration.  How would I do that? I was thinking that by doing div.row label it will only applied to all the label inside a div class="row"

```
div.row label{
    font-weight: bold;
}

<div class="row"><label>row 1</label> : <input type="text"/></div>
<div><label>row 2</label> : <input type="text"/></div>
```

Comment: Seems find to me http://jsfiddle.net/aH2tG/

Comment: So what's the problem? Is it not working for you?

Comment: My bad it was because someone added a row class to a container.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how variable your structure is, you can use 
    div.row:first-child { /*css here*/ }
or 
    div.row:nth-child(n) { /*css here*/ }
to select the elements within the div of the chosen class